# Observable not firing during Angular 2 HTTP request

Tags: ajax, typescript, angular, ionic2, es6-promise

I have the following method, using Ionic 2 with Angular 2:

```
private login(params: any, url: string){
    var p = new Promise<JsonResult>((resolve, reject) => {
        let body = JSON.stringify(params);
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
        this.http.post(url, body, options)
            .timeout(10000, new Error('Timeout exceeded during login'))
            .subscribe((res) => {
                let json = new JsonResult().deserialize(res.json());
                resolve(json);   
            }, (err) => { 
                reject(err);
            });
    });
    return p;
}
```

No matter what I do, the subscribe is not working as expected. 
The error handler never gets fired. Not even after the timeout has exceeded.

Is this a known problem, or is there something wrong with my syntax?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: For those wondering, I use the following import:

import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions, Response, HTTP_PROVIDERS } from 'angular2/http';

and inject it into my class inside the constructor

Comment: Please rather edit your question and add additional information there. Code is cumbersome to read in comments.

Comment: What do you import regarding rxjs?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return a `Promise` I would do it this way:

```
private login(params: any, url: string){
        let body = JSON.stringify(params);
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
        return this.http.post(url, body, options)
            .timeout(10000, new Error('Timeout exceeded during login'))
            .catch(err => {
              console.log(err);
              return Observable.of([]));
            })
            .map((res) => {
                return new JsonResult().deserialize(res.json());
            }) 
            .toPromise();
}
```

Comment: Will this not only catch the timeout?
I also don't think the map function will be sufficient for me, since I do a lot of other (async) tasks within the success handler, such as storing the returned json to the database. I understand http will return a promise, but shouldn't it be possible to nest promises?

Comment: Sure it's possible but it seems a bit cumbersome. There are operators (like flatMap) that wait for async calls. I think code will be much more readable the Rx way than mixing observables and promises.

Comment: I got a working with a small variation on your code! Thanks for the input on using promises instead of observables... helped me a lot!